# Selenium Webdriver (Python) - Unable to locate element inside nested iframes

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, css-selectors

I am trying to scrape some data from an iframe located within a webpage. The URL of the webpage is https://www.nissanoflithiasprings.com/schedule-service. I am trying to access the button shown in the image below:

[image]

When I right-click on the button (located inside the iframe) to view the source code, I am able to see the HTML id and name (see screenshot below):

[image]

The "id" for the button is "new_customer_button". However, when I use selenium webdriver's `driver.find_element_by_id("new_customer_button")` to access the button, the code is not able to locate the button inside the iframe and throws the following error:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"new_customer_button"}
```

Below is the code that I have tried so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\gh455\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.nissanoflithiasprings.com/schedule-service")

dest_iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[0] 
driver.switch_to.frame(dest_iframe)

driver.find_element_by_id("new_customer_button")
```

Not sure why this is happening. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element is inside multiple `<iframe>` tags, you need to switch to them one by one. You should also maximize the window and use explicit wait as it take some time to load

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\gh455\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.nissanoflithiasprings.com/schedule-service")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# first frame - by css selector
wait.until(ec.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[src^="https://consumer.xtime.com"]')))

# second frame - by ID
wait.until(ec.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it('xt01'))

driver.find_element_by_id("new_customer_button")
```

Answer (score 2):

To `click()` on the element with text as **Make · Year · Model** as the the desired element is within an nested `<iframe>`s so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired parent *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired child *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `element_to_be_clickable()`.
- You can use the following solution:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("https://www.nissanoflithiasprings.com/schedule-service")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src*='com/scheduling']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src*='consumerportal']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.button.button--action.btn.btn-secondary#new_customer_button"))).click()
    ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: nissan]

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)